# How to fix an error "External component has thrown an exception"

Tags: powerbi-desktop

How to fix an error "External component has thrown an exception"

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Screenshots in general should be avoided in posts here. In your case, it gives us no useful information anyway — nothing we can use to diagnose the issue. Instead, could you edit your post to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That will probably include the output of the "Copy details to clipboard" option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.